# How to prevent base64 encoding of AWS Lambda - POST Body payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, base64, payload

I recently migrated code to a new AWS cloud account. My Lambda function has not changed but I had to setup / configure the entry point API Gateway.

After this I find that I am not getting a cleartext `event[body]` and seen an encoded value
On investigation of the event, I find this `isBase64Encoded': True` in Production.

On the contrary, when I tried a dummy/test invocation via postman the `event[body]` comes AS IS in clear text.

1. Is there any particular configuration when creating the AWS API or Routes that prevents the Base64 Encoding of the POST `event[Body]`. What is the reason for this behavior?
2. Is there a way to decode this value back to cleartext in python?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.